# Arch Boot Hook: Allocation zramctl fails to allocate

Tags: arch-linux, ram, hook

OS Version: 5.9.14-arch1-1 Kernel

I am trying to figure out how I can load the whole `/` directory into the RAM when starting up.
I found a little helper here:
https://github.com/arcmags/ramroot

So, when the `ramroot` hook starts to run, it will set up the zram module:

```
modprobe zram
```

Next, we will allocate some memory with...

```
zramctl -f -s 10M
```

When my OS is started up, this command works fine and I can mount the `zram0` device.
But in this boot mode, I get this error:

```
/dev/zram0: failed to set disksize (.... bytes): Cannot allocate memory
```

Does anyone know where the issue may be?
Are there modules missing to get the operation done?

This is my current hook order:

```
HOOKS=(base udev ramroot autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard fsck)
```

Comment: `how I can load the whole / directory into the Ram when starting up` _From where_? Where is the actual whole `/` directory _stored_ right now? I once wrote [mkinitcpio-archivetmpfs](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/mkinitcpio-archivetmpfs/) that could for example  download `alpine` linux chroot (ie. "whole / directory") and uncompress it into tmpfs mounted `/newroot` and then boot into it, basically running alpine from ram.

Comment: The root directory is on a SSD Partition right now and gets mounted from /dev/sdc2 to / in fstab file. As far as I know it must be possible to copy the partition into ram and then booting it. (May took a while) I'll checkout your work!

Comment: First do it manually. Boot into `initrd`. Then mount `/dev/sdc2` for example into `mnt` and mount `tmpfs` into `/newroot` then `cp -a` all files from `/dev/sdc2` into `/newroot`. Then type `exit` and it should boot from `/newroot`, hopefully.

Comment: @Toby Speight I created a hook that does exactly what you want to do (basically, a much simpler version of ramroot). It works flawlessly with the current official kernel, but if I try to switch the kernel to a custom one (built with "native" optimizations, I get exactly the same error you, and I also have no idea why it is happening

Comment: @user1593842, I don't know why you aimed that comment at me.  All I did was improve the grammar and spelling; I'm not that interested in the question otherwise.

Comment: @Toby Speight Sorry, I wasn't paying attention and thought you were the one who asked the question. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I created a hook that does the same thing you want to do and, even though at first it worked, after a kernel update I started receiving the same error message.

I think the culprit may be the change of `zram` default compression algorithm. I believe newer kernel versions started using `zstd` as the new default.

What worked for me was adding the `zstd` module in the `build()` function of the hook, using `add_module zstd`.

And, of course, if instead of `zstd` you are planning to use anything else, add that module instead.

The error message is very misleading, but I was able to figure out what was missing based on [this](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=211173)